# How to call Postgres function in DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbix-class

I'm currently playing around with [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) and I'm wondering how to call an existing Postgres function in a certain db schema using DBIx.

My DBI code:

```
my $table = $self->{dbh}->quote_identifier(
                    undef,
                    'foo',
                    'myFunction'
                    );

my $sqlst = qq{ SELECT foobar FROM $table($some_data); };
```

The things I found so far, would be to call said function using the dbh object retrieved from my [DBIx::Class::Schema](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema) object:

```
my $return_data = {};

my $sql = qq{SELECT foobar FROM "foo"."myFunction"($some_data)};

$self->{schema}->storage->dbh_do( sub {
    my ($storage, $dbh) = @_;
    $menu_list = $dbh->selectrow_hashref(
        $sql,
        { slice => {} }
    );
});
```

Is there a better/easier solution than this?

I also stumbled upon [DBIx::ProcedureCall](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::ProcedureCall), but I couldn't get it to work when using a DB schema.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use [SQL Functions as Table Sources](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-TABLE-FUNCTIONS), it should be possible to create a virtual [DBIx::Class::ResultSource::View](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSource/View.pod) like this:

```
package MyApp::Schema::Result::MyFunction;

use base qw/DBIx::Class::Core/;

__PACKAGE__->table_class('DBIx::Class::ResultSource::View');

__PACKAGE__->table('myFunction');
__PACKAGE__->result_source_instance->is_virtual(1);
__PACKAGE__->result_source_instance->view_definition(
    'SELECT foobar FROM "foo"."myFunction"(?)'
);
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
    'foobar' => {
        data_type => 'varchar',
    },
);
```

The view can be used like this:

```
my $rs = $schema->resultset('MyFunction')->select({}, {
    bind => [ 'arg' ],
});
```

This will create a subquery that isn't really necessary:

```
SELECT me.foobar FROM (SELECT foobar FROM "foo"."myFunction"(?)) me
```

But I think it should work.

Comment: I was kinda hoping there was a shorter way to call DB functions, instead of creating Views for each of them ;-) But I guess I'm gonna do it like this now. Thanks a lot!